# Playing videos in loop, one after another before previous ends

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've got a slider, in which 3 videos must run one after another in a loop, however, each following video must play a specific time BEFORE previous video ends (while still running). Code below runs the second video, but I've got no idea how to mark the right index, because obviously it triggers multiple time after reaching a point in the video. Any ideas?

```
$('.slide .video').on('timeupdate', function (e) {
    if (this.currentTime * 1000 > this.duration * 1000 - transitionDuration) {
        $activeSlide = $('.slide').eq(activeIndex + 1);
        $activeVideo = $activeSlide.find('.video');
        $activeVideo[0].play();
        $('.slide').eq(activeIndex + 1).addClass('is-animated');
    }
});

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <video class="video"></video>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <video class="video"></video>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <video class="video"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the html snippet for the slider would help a great deal